# How to sign SegWit Transaction without using third party libraries (step by step)

Tags: segregated-witness, bip174-psbt

I have a PSBT transaction. My code parsed it into its component parts: 3 maps - global input, output. I based on the document [1](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/transactions.html#raw-transaction-format). I parsed each transaction into separate fields. Found all scripts and their type, and got a private key for scripts.
What steps need to be taken to sign the transaction, without using third-party libraries, step by step (which fields should be used)

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without more information. Can you provide an example? What languages are you using? Is using `bitcoin-cli` an option?

Comment: I write ma stack on C ( embedded application). I need an understanding of what needs to be done. In the python, c++ source code and documentation, the field names do not match.

Comment: This might help, as it at least gives a full example in Golang: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96283/how-to-sign-a-psbt-transaction

Comment: Now you need to understand how class members correspond to transaction fields. [link](https://btcinformation.org/en/developer-reference#raw-transaction-format)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.